# Why does `Selection.Font.Bold = 1` work as expected but not `Selection.Range.Bold = 1` (Word Interop)

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

Here is a C# program using Word Interop:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application app = new Application();
        app.Visible = true;
        Document doc = app.Documents.Add(Visible: true);

        Selection selection = app.Selection;
        selection.TypeText("Hello, friend");
        selection.TypeParagraph();
        selection.Range.Bold = 1;
        selection.TypeText("Hello, world??");
        selection.TypeParagraph();
        selection.Font.Bold = 1;
        selection.TypeText("Hello, world!!");
        selection.TypeParagraph();
    }
}
```

Here's the result:

[image: Resulting Word document]

Why is only `Hello, World!!` in bold font and not also `Hello, World??`? What is the difference between using `Selection.Range.Bold` and `Selection.Font.Bold`?

Comment: Try selection.Range.Bold = True instead of = 1 . Maybe depends of your Office version.

Comment: Pretty sure the true value for bold is `-1`. Alternatively `selection.Font.Bold = true;` may work. I haven't tested either.

Comment: I'm using *Microsoft Word 12.0 Object Library*. The type of `Range.Bold` is `int` according to intellisense. Replacing `1` with `-1` didn't work, but replacing `Range` with `Font` does (see my update to the question).

Comment: Selection.TypeText() doesn't do what you think it does.  Its affect depends on the Options.ReplaceSelection property, clearly it is False.  So text gets inserted *before* the selection.

Comment: Thanks, Hans, but unfortunately I can't say I'm any wiser. I appreciate that `Selection.TypeText()` inserts before the selection, but I don't see how that has any bearing on the question.